Cumulative totals in Oracle SQL
I have the following table
CP          ROK DOPIS_C
-----------------------
6059150790  2014    C
6059150790  2015    C
6059150790  2016    C
6059150790  2017     
6059150790  2018    C
6059150790  2019     
6059150790  2020    C
6059150790  2021    C
6059150790  2022    C
6059150790  2023     
6059150790  2024     

I need this output
CP          ROK DOPIS_C     RN_C1
---------------------------------
6059150790  2014    C         1
6059150790  2015    C         2
6059150790  2016    C         3
6059150790  2017                 
6059150790  2018    C         1
6059150790  2019                 
6059150790  2020    C         1
6059150790  2021    C         2
6059150790  2022    C         3
6059150790  2023             
6059150790  2024                 

in the RN_C1 column the number of previous records is counted, where DOPIS_C has the value C and if there is a null value in the previous record in the DOPIS_C column, the counter is reset
I try this
SELECT 
    CP,
    ROK,
    DOPIS_C,
    CASE 
        WHEN DOPIS_C = 'C' THEN 
            CASE 
                WHEN lag(DOPIS_C) OVER (ORDER BY ROK) IS NULL THEN 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ROK)
                WHEN lag(DOPIS_C) OVER (ORDER BY ROK) = 'C' THEN 
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN DOPIS_C = 'C' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY ROK) 
            END
        ELSE 0 
    END AS POSILANI
FROM 
    table;

but result is
6059150790  2014    C   1
6059150790  2015    C   2
6059150790  2016    C   3
6059150790  2017        0
6059150790  2018    C   5
6059150790  2019        0
6059150790  2020    C   7
6059150790  2021    C   6
6059150790  2022    C   7
6059150790  2023        0
6059150790  2024        0


From Oracle 12, you can use MATCH_RECOGNIZE for row-by-row pattern matching:
SELECT cp,
       rok,
       dopis_c,
       CASE dopis_c WHEN 'C' THEN posilani END AS posilani
FROM   table_name
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY cp
         ORDER BY rok
         MEASURES
           COUNT(dopis_c) AS posilani
         ALL ROWS PER MATCH
         PATTERN ( C+ | NOT_C )
         DEFINE C AS dopis_c = 'C'
       );

Or, in earlier versions you can use multiple analytic functions:
SELECT cp,
       rok,
       dopis_c,
       rn,
       CASE dopis_c
       WHEN 'C'
       THEN rn - COALESCE(
              LAST_VALUE(CASE WHEN dopis_c IS NULL THEN rn END) IGNORE NULLS
                OVER (PARTITION BY cp ORDER BY rok),
              0
            )
       END AS posilani
FROM (
  SELECT cp,
         rok,
         dopis_c,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cp ORDER BY rok) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
);

or:
SELECT cp,
       rok,
       dopis_c,
       CASE dopis_c
       WHEN 'C'
       THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cp, dopis_c, c_grp ORDER BY rok)
       END AS posilani
FROM (
  SELECT cp,
         rok,
         dopis_c,
         COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY cp ORDER BY rok)
           - COUNT(dopis_c) OVER (PARTITION BY cp ORDER BY rok) AS c_grp
  FROM   table_name
)
ORDER BY
       cp,
       rok

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (CP, ROK, DOPIS_C) AS
SELECT 6059150790, 2014, 'C'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6059150790, 2015, 'C'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6059150790, 2016, 'C'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6059150790, 2017, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6059150790, 2018, 'C'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6059150790, 2019, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6059150790, 2020, 'C'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6059150790, 2021, 'C'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6059150790, 2022, 'C'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6059150790, 2023, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6059150790, 2024, NULL FROM DUAL;

All outputs:



CP
ROK
DOPIS_C
POSILANI




6059150790
2014
C
1


6059150790
2015
C
2


6059150790
2016
C
3


6059150790
2017
null
null


6059150790
2018
C
1


6059150790
2019
null
null


6059150790
2020
C
1


6059150790
2021
C
2


6059150790
2022
C
3


6059150790
2023
null
null


6059150790
2024
null
null



fiddle

Thank you
and if I wanted to include another column in the calculation, where the principle of calculation would be the same.
e.g. column dopis_k, where it would retrieve the number of occurrences of 'K'

@feoftheda In general, if you have a follow on question then you should ask a new question. In this case, you can run MATCH_RECOGNIZE twice or use analytic functions - a few examples are in this fiddle.

You can also do it without MATCH_RECOGNIZE but with a subquery:
select cp, rok_dopis, c, 
    nvl2(c,row_number() over(partition by cp,  c || n order by rok_dopis),null) as rn_c1
from (
    select d.*, 
        sum(case when c is null then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by cp order by rok_dopis) as n    
    from table_name d 
)
order by rok_dopis
;

